# Infinite loop + wrong output when trying to get key/value pair from localStorage in React.useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to GET queries from my API with all key=fld_id/value=true pairs in local storage "Selected Fields".

This is how "Selected Fields" appears in the localStorage (they are stored form checkbox form submission):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GITnB.png

It keeps running an infinite loop in the backend that eventually crashes my browser and inserts wrong fld_id (which is the key in the localStorage): https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5QBm.png

```
const [monitoringData, setMonitoringData] = React.useState(null);

const selected = localStorage.getItem("Selected Fields");

  Object.keys(selected).forEach((fld_id) => {
    axios
      .get("/api/parsed-logs-list/?fld_id=" + fld_id)
      .then((response) => {
        setMonitoringData([...monitoringData, fld_id.response.data]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setMonitoringData({ status: "error" });
      });
  });
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue please?

Edit: Solution provided in a later comment below to avoid confusions.

Comment: It is advised that when updating state using a previous state (like you're doing with setMonitoringData([...monitoringData ...) the parameter of your setter should be a callback that takes the previous state and return new state so it should look like this `setMonitoringData(prev=>[...prev,fld_id.response.data])`

Comment: That's because state changes are not applied instantly but are queued for execution thus if you use old state the way you did there's a chance it gets ugly

Comment: When I change it with prev it gives me "Uncaught TypeError: prev is not iterable"

Comment: Try initialising the monitoringData with empty array [] instead of null

Comment: Or maybe show me how you wrote it

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answers @AlaaEddineCherif
Here's how I declared the state with Context API:
  const [monitoringData, setMonitoringData] = React.useState(null);

I'll try your [] solution and get back to you!

Comment: I would've liked to see how you set state. Hope i'm helping :D

Comment: @AlaaEddineCherif Now it's working without infinite loop and giving me the right queries for my selection, however it gives a new error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')" :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246946/discussion-between-aleya-and-alaa-eddine-cherif).

Comment: The reason for that is because you're getting data from fld_id.response.data but you should get it from the response (the one in red )

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you must wrap your side effect in `useEffect` hook (otherwise after each rerender you make request and update state, that cause to infinite loop). Secondly, type of value you receive from localStorage is `string` not `object`, you must parse with `JSON.parse(selected)` before calling `Object.keys`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it gets the fld_id's correctly but it still loops infinitely on them (keys 787 and 788 were in local storage) even though I wrapped the entire block in useEffect as you can see in the screenshot: 
https://i.imgur.com/6Eu2A6c.png

Comment: if you're using useEffect you shoud give it an array of dependencies as a third parameter .   That tells it when it should re-execute , if no array is given it will loop infinitely. You can give it an empty array and it only executes once

Comment: Thank you! I've set it to an empty array. It's weird because when I did that before it still looped infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Mike and @AlaaEddineCherif, it now works as intended so I'm posting the solution in a different post in case it will be of help to someone else one day.

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const selected = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selected_fld_id"));

    Object.keys(selected).forEach((fld_id) => {
      axios
        .get("/api/parsed-logs-list/?fld_id=" + fld_id)
        .then((response) => {
          setMonitoringData((prev) => [...prev, response.data]);
          // console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setMonitoringData({ status: "error" });
        });
    });
  }, []);
```